# Serving Rest calls through web controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

Can regular *spring web controller* be used for mapping to restful request or do i need to create explicitly separate `@Restful` controller
for the same ?

The reason for asking this I have existing web controller and couple of methods(which i want to map to rest request) in them are returning data in json form already

I understand best will be to separate them out to make it modular and readable but still I would like to know whether it is technically feasible to use existing web controller as rest controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`docs`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) of `@RestController`

> A convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody.
>   Types that carry this annotation are treated as controllers where @RequestMapping methods assume @ResponseBody semantics by default.

So with `@RestController` you get the normal Spring `@Controller + @ResponseBody`.

You can definitely use `@Controller` for your ***Restful api*** but then you also need to use `@ResponseBody` explicitly for your Model/Entity conversion.